# knowning how many rows are left with mysql_fetch_*

Tags: php, mysql

consider this simple code:

```
$q=mysql_query('SELECT [...]');
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   //Do something with data
   //And write how many rows are left
}
```

Is there a way to know how many rows will return mysql_fetch_assoc() inside the while ?

ADD1:

I know I can manually count inside the while. I was asking if there is a mysql function that can do the job, something like mysql_data_*

example:

```
while(..){
    echo mysql_num_query($q);
}
```

Comment: @anonymous voter: add a comment when you down voting thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request the number of rows in the array with mysql_num_rows($q) then decrement the count in the while loop.

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
  $rows --;
  //Do something with data
  //And write how many rows are left
  echo $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

`$numRows = mysql_num_rows($q)`;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mysql_num_rows` function [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
$q=mysql_query('SELECT [...]');
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   //Do something with data
   //And write how many rows are left
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the only way is running count query before and then having some counter inside loop.

```
$q1 = mysql_query('select count(*) [...]');
$q2 = mysql_query('select [...]');

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2))
{
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This is more work - an extra server query, plus the count increases instead of decreasing.